Does Palantir driver support being loaded from an unmapped UNC path?
We have the Palantir Foundry JDBC Driver placed in System Share of our application (FME Flow) and it returns a URI error. Does Palantir driver not support being loaded from an unmapped UNC path?
In our testing, we had to use a locally mounted drive to the Windows VM. The local mounted drive was assigned the letter W and was successful with the JDBC driver jar file.
Is this a known issue or bug?
URI Error when jar file placed in system share
2024-02-20 18:51:07|   0.0|  0.0|INFORM|JDBC Reader: Creating connection using connection string 'jdbc:foundrysql://paloma.palantirfoundry.com' and properties '{password=************, user=blahtest}'
2024-02-20 18:51:07|   0.0|  0.0|INFORM|JDBC Reader: Driver class 'com.palantir.foundry.sql.jdbc.FoundryJdbcDriver' is being loaded from '/fmeflow232share/resources/engine/Plugins/Java/foundry-sql-jdbc-driver-3.9.0-withdep.jar'
2024-02-20 18:51:07|   0.0|  0.0|ERROR |java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component

    at java.base/java.io.File.<init>(Unknown Source)

    at com.palantir.foundry.sql.os.utils.FileUtils.toFile(FileUtils.java:47)

    at com.palantir.foundry.sql.os.utils.FileUtils.getJarFolder(FileUtils.java:23)

    at com.palantir.foundry.sql.jdbc.config.JdbcIniFileReader.readConfigFile(JdbcIniFileReader.java:31)

    at com.palantir.foundry.sql.jdbc.JdbcConnectionStringParser.parseFoundryJdbcUri(JdbcConnectionStringParser.java:113)

    at com.palantir.foundry.sql.jdbc.JdbcConnectionStringParser.tryParseJdbcUri(JdbcConnectionStringParser.java:60)

    at com.palantir.foundry.sql.jdbc.FoundryJdbcDriver.connect(FoundryJdbcDriver.java:69)

    at COM.safe.fme.jdbc.JdbcCommon.openConnection(JdbcCommon.java:575)

    at COM.safe.fme.jdbc.JdbcReader.openHelper(JdbcReader.java:198)

    at COM.safe.fme.jdbc.JdbcReader.open(JdbcReader.java:167)

Successful load when jar file is placed in the application's install directory. Taking the jar file out of the System Share (E:/Program Data/Safe Software/FMEFlow/resources/engine/plugins/java) and placing it in the install directory “E:/Program Files/FME Flow/Server/fme/plugins/" got it working.
2024-02-20 18:54:31|   0.7|  0.0|INFORM|JDBC Reader: Creating connection using connection string 'jdbc:foundrysql://paloma.palantirfoundry.com' and properties '{password=************, user=blahtest}'
2024-02-20 18:54:35|   2.3|  1.6|INFORM|JDBC Reader: Driver class 'com.palantir.foundry.sql.jdbc.FoundryJdbcDriver' is being loaded from '/C:/Program Files/FMEFlow/Server/fme/plugins/foundry-sql-jdbc-driver-3.9.0-withdep.jar'

Successful load when jar file is placed in the application's system share on local mounted drive.
2024-04-30 13:36:14|   0.9|  0.0|INFORM|JDBC Reader: Creating connection using connection string 'jdbc:foundrysql://paloma.palantirfoundry.com' and properties '{password=************, user=blahtest}'
2024-04-30 13:36:17|   2.6|  1.7|INFORM|JDBC Reader: Driver class 'com.palantir.foundry.sql.jdbc.FoundryJdbcDriver' is being loaded from '/W:/fmeflowshare/resources/engine/Plugins/Java/foundry-sql-jdbc-driver-3.9.0-withdep.jar'

